# Social sign-in (OAuth) gender required

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my userpool I have marked gender as a required attribute and I think it is causing some problem when configuring oauth with Facebook and Google.

I have followed the steps in the Amplify documentation to configure the social sign-in [doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js)
but I'm getting an error in the url, something like this: `https://auth.mydomain.com/sigin/?error_description=attributes+required%3A+%5Bgender%5D&state=LdMFbexCz81loAUnV66hue9LSuta5zcn&error=invalid_request#` in the case of google after choosing the account to log in and in facebook first of all

note: I use amplify in react-native

Comment: Google doesn't know my gender, and I certainly never authorized Facebook to tell you mine.  You need to get rid of that requirement.

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately I cannot remove the requirement from my userpool because it is not possible. How can I change the userpool used by amplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito doesn't allow changing the attributes after creating the pool. On AWS Console > General Settings > Attributes, you'll see `These attributes were selected when the pool was created and cannot be changed.`

You could give this a try: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-change-user-pool-attributes/ which suggests creating a new pool and migrating users to the new pool.